# Помогите определить ошибку в коде

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml, c++14

Я совсем новичек в програмировании и недавно решил попробовать написать тетрис используя SFML. Но у меня возникла проблема так как по каким то причинам масив классов(этот клас содержыт спрайт в виде члена ) создается как то неправильно. Компилятор ни на что не жалуется, но при попытке отрисовки спрайтов тетрамино( отдельных 4х квадратиков) ничего не происходит, а просто создается окно. У меня есть два предположения по этому поводу:

- спрайт сам уничтожается при выходе из блока(или при попытке доступа, я не знаю))) но как тогда в клас вообще добавить член-спрайт что б он нормально создавался и инициализировался???
- я как то неправильно подключил sfml.

Извиняюсь за некраткость вопроса. Это мой первый пост. на все выше сказане мне ответ не требуется, просто помогите найти ошибку. Буду очень благодарен всем.
PS: извиняюсь за public члены в класах, я дкмал сделать для них геттеры позже.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
using namespace sf;

int getRandomNumber(int min,int max)
{
    static const double fraction = 1 / (static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX) + 1.0);
    return static_cast<int>(rand() * fraction * (max-min + 1) + min);
}

class Piece
{
    int PieceX;
    int PieceY;
    Texture tetraminoTexture;
public:
    Sprite pieceSprite;
    Piece(){}
    Piece(int type, int x, int y )
    {
        tetraminoTexture.loadFromFile("D:\\Навчання\\С++\\Textures\\tiles.png");
        pieceSprite.setTexture(tetraminoTexture);
        pieceSprite.setTextureRect(IntRect((type*18), 0, 18, 18));
        PieceX= x ;
        PieceY = y;
        pieceSprite.setPosition(static_cast<float>(PieceX), static_cast<float>(PieceY));
    }
    int getPieceX() { return PieceX; }
    int getPieceY() { return PieceY; }
    void setPieceX(int x) { PieceX = x; }
    void setPieceY(int y) { PieceX = y; }
};

class Tetramino
{
    int m_type;
    int tetraminos[7][4]
    {
    {1,3,5,7},
    {2,4,5,7},
    {3,5,4,6},
    {3,5,4,7},
    {2,3,5,7},
    {3,5,7,6},
    {2,3,4,5}

    };
public:
    Piece tetramino[4];
    Tetramino()
    {
        m_type = getRandomNumber(0,7);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            tetramino[i] = Piece(m_type, (tetraminos[m_type][i] % 2) * 18, (tetraminos[m_type][i] / 2) * 18);
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    rand();
    
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(320, 480), "Tetris");
    Tetramino example;
    
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }
        window.clear(Color::White);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            window.draw(example.tetramino[i].pieceSprite);
        }
        
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: @user7860670 А оно тут нужно? SFML не должен сам нормально обрабатывать копирование/перемещение?

Comment: Пробовали запустить минимальный пример отображения спрайта из доков https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php? Так будет понятно, проблема в вашем коде или в неправильных путях/подключении SFML

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, нужно. Однако SFML этого не делает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вызове неявно сгенерированного оператора копирования, например в `tetramino[i] = Piece(m_type, (tetraminos[m_type][i] % 2) * 18, (tetraminos[m_type][i] / 2) * 18);` скопированный экземпляр класса `Sprite` будет продолжать ссылаться на объект `Texture` в разрушаемом объекте с правой стороны. Соответственно тут надо создавать пользовательские конструкторы и операторы копирования и перемещения. А когда нет уверенности в правильной работе этих операторов, генерируемых компилятором, то их следует явно запрещать.

> It is important to note that the sf::Sprite instance doesn't copy the texture that it uses, it only keeps a reference to it. Thus, a sf::Texture must not be destroyed while it is used by a sf::Sprite (i.e. never write a function that uses a local sf::Texture instance for creating a sprite).

Еще у вас в конструкторе по-умолчанию не инициализируются поля PieceX PieceY.