# An internal OpenGL call failed in Texture.cpp(98)

Tags: c++, классы, sfml

Ошибка

```
An internal OpenGL call failed in Texture.cpp(98).
Expression:
   glFlush()
Error description:
   GL_INVALID_OPERATION
   The specified operation is not allowed in the current state.
```

Методом исключения выяснил что ошибка в *this->texture1.loadFromFile* но не знаю почему

```
#pragma once
#include "Figures.h"
class Pawn : public Figures
{
public:
    Pawn(int x, int y, Teams t) : Figures(x, y, t) { 
        if (t == Teams::WHITE)
            this->texture1.loadFromFile("images/2.png");
        else
            this->texture1.loadFromFile("images/-2.png");
        this->figure1.setTexture(texture1);
    }
};
```

```
#include <vector>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
enum Teams
{
    WHITE, BLACK
};
struct Cord
{ int x;
  int y; };
class Figures
{
public:
    Figures() {

    }
    Figures(int x, int y, Teams t) {
        this->MyCord.x = x;
        this->MyCord.y = y;
        this->isSelect = false;
        this->t = t;
    }
    Cord getCord() {
        return this->MyCord;
    }
    Sprite getSprite() {
        return this->figure1;
    }
    void SetPos(int x, int y) {
        figure1.setPosition(x, y);
    }
protected:
    Cord MyCord;
    std::vector<Cord> myMoves;
    bool isSelect;
    Teams t;
    Texture texture1;
    Sprite figure1;
};
```

Comment: Игнорировать возвращаемое значение `loadFromFile`  нельзя, нарушать [правило 3 / 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) - тоже.

Comment: Можно поподробнее

Comment: Куда уж подробнее, разве что самому переписать правильно...

Comment: Если создавать просто экземпляр класса:`Pawn k(1, 1, Teams::BLACK);` то ошибки нет но если так как мне надо `figures.push_back(Pawn(i, 1, Teams::BLACK));` то есть

Comment: тут такая же проблема как и в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157774/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5/1157831#1157831

Comment: Можно через указатель `Texture* texture = new Texture();
   texture->loadFromFile("images/2.png");
  this->figure.setTexture(*texture);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Texture* texture = new Texture();
        if (t == Teams::WHITE)
            texture->loadFromFile("images/2.png");
        else
            texture->loadFromFile("images/-2.png");
        this->figure.setTexture(*texture);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]